# Specify a vector in circular coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems

If circular coordinates are understood as:

[image: circularc]

Then a point is indicated by ($r$, $\theta$). But how should a vector be specified? ($r-r_0$, $\theta$-$\theta_0$) ?

$\theta - \theta_0$ seem a wrong step, or is it a curved vector?

Comment: $(a,b)$ is just a representation of the coeficients of a 2-dimensional space.

Comment: I think a valid question is: How represent a cartesian vector field in polar coordinates? Are you looking for this?

Comment: @DiegoMath no, I think a vector can be written in this coordinate system, isn't it? It has nothing to do wth cartesian coordinates...